# Run a trigger when disabling a customer user

Tags: trigger, contact, user, customer-portal

I want to write a trigger that will mark a checkbox on the **contact** object once a user clicks on the 'Manage External Users'->'Disable Customer User'
[image]

This is the trigger I wrote, it does not run when I click on the disable customer user:

```
trigger User on User(after insert, after update) {
        Set < Id > contactIds = new Set < Id > ();
        for (User u: Trigger.new) {
            if (u.ContactId == null && Trigger.oldmap.get(u.id).ContactId != null) {
                contactIds.add(Trigger.oldmap.get(u.id).ContactId);
            }
            if (contactIds.size() > 0) {
                List < Contact > contacts = [select id, Has_Access_to_Customer_Portal__c from Contact where Id in: contactIds];
                for (Contact c: contacts) {
                    c.Has_Access_to_Customer_Portal__c = false;
                }
                update contacts;
            }
        }
```

I guess the answer would be that the trigger object should be a contact, but I don't really know how to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprise... I did a bit of debug and found out
 **if (u.ContactId == null )** returns false in after update trigger. Thus you cannot use this field to determine if the Customer/Partner user is disabled or not.

I believe once the user is disabled, internally they remove the association of User with contact without running a trigger.

Can we still write trigger when customer user is diabled ? yes.

User object has a field named as **IsPortalEnabled** you can use it to your advantage. So your trigger will be like.

```
trigger User on User(after insert, after update) {
    Set < Id > contactIds = new Set < Id > ();
    for (User u: Trigger.new) {
        if (u.IsPortalEnabled == false && Trigger.oldmap.get(u.id).IsPortalEnabled ==true) {
            contactIds.add(Trigger.oldmap.get(u.id).ContactId);
        }
        if (contactIds.size() > 0) {
            List < Contact > contacts = [select id, Has_Access_to_Customer_Portal__c from Contact where Id in: contactIds];
            for (Contact c: contacts) {
                c.Has_Access_to_Customer_Portal__c = false;
            }
            updateContactsInFuture(JSON.serialize(contacts)); //Should use future. as its Mixed DML.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting MIXED_DML_OPERATION error, maybe I should use @future?

Comment: yeah,,, Its Setup Non Setup object. So yes. Future/queuable.  Reaching this exception means your trigger is getting called and you are updating contact which was the original issue.

Comment: using IsPortalEnabled (instead of isActive) and the future annotation did the trick, thank you @Pranay!